# Find the limit as $x \rightarrow 0$ for $\frac{x(1+\cos(x))}{\sin(x) \cos(x)}$ without using De l'Hôpital

Tags: calculus, limits

> Find the limit:
>
> $$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x(1+\cos(x))}{\sin(x) \cos(x)}$$
>
> **without** using De l'Hôpital's method.

First I tried direct substitution, so

$$(0) \times (1+\cos x) = 0$$
$$\sin(0) \times \cos(0) = 0$$

0/0 is undefined.

So then I tried this

$$ x \times (1+\cos(x)) * (1-\cos(x))  / \sin(x) \cos(x) \times (1-\cos(x))$$
$$ x \times (1-\cos(x)^2  / \sin(x) \cos(x) \times (1-\cos(x))$$
$$ \sqrt{ x} \times \sin(x)  / \sqrt{\sin(x) \cos(x) \times \cos(x)^2\times \sin(x)}$$

I was sure I was on the right track, trying to get $\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ which = 1 but I had no luck.

Comment: Write your expression as $\textstyle{1\over {\sin x\over x}}\cdot{1+\cos x\over \cos x}$ and take the limit of each factor separately.

Comment: Awesome, thank you. You are a genius! @DavidMitra

Comment: @Ghozt I would like you to know that ALL CAPS is among the rudest of practices on the internet, and should be avoided at all costs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $\frac{x(1+\cos(x))}{\sin(x) \cos(x)}=\frac{1}{\frac{\sin(x)}{x}} \cdot \frac{1+\cos(x)}{\cos(x)} $ As $x$ approaches $0$, the first term evaluates to $1$ and the second to...., so the whole function will tend to...?

Answer (score 1):

One method :

When $x \rightarrow 0$, we have :

$$\sin(x) \sim x $$

It allows you to say that, when $x \rightarrow 0$, we have :

$$ \frac{x(1+\cos(x))}{\sin(x)\cos(x)} \sim \frac{1+\cos(x)}{\cos(x)} \mathop{\rightarrow} \limits_{x \rightarrow 0}  2 $$

So,

$$ \lim \limits_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{x(1+\cos(x))}{\sin(x)\cos(x)} = 2 $$